# Weakened Chebyshev inequality?

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ is integrable (on some measure space), is it true that:

$$t\nu\{x : f(x) \geq t\}\ \leq \int_{f \geq t}f \, dv\qquad ?$$

$\nu$ is of course the measure, and $t \geq 0$

I'm having trouble proving this, it seems it should be somewhat obvious.

Comment: An extra factor $t$ on LHS would make it work.

Comment: Yes I meant the extra factor of t, typed it too quickly! So it works as edited above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Observe that: $$t1_{\{f\geq t\}}\leq f1_{\{f\geq t\}}$$ and take integrals on both sides.